# Replacing cranks on SRAM Force AXS

Tags: road-bike, crankset, sram, torque-wrench

I've purchased some shorter cranks for my SRAM Force AXS eTap bike, and I'm trying to decide between learning and swapping them myself vs. bringing it into a LBS.

Pros of doing it myself:

- learn for the future
- save money on LBS costs (plus I'd have to pay for a cab there/back)
- satisfaction

Cons:

- My bike is very expensive and I'd hate to break something/have something go wrong on a ride
- Would need to buy a larger torque wrench (not a huge con given I'll have one for the future)
- Minor, but I'm slightly worried my small torque wrench isn't very accurate, I left it at 6nm for a month or so instead of the lowest setting

As far as I can see the process would be:

- Loosen 2mm preload adjuster and unscrew
- Take off crankset with 8mm hex
- Take cranks off spider by undoing the 8 T20 bolts
- Swap and replace bolts at 4NM (greased?)
- Grease spindle and splines
- Install and tighten again with 8mm hex at 54NM
- Tap crank side with mallet and retighten preload adjuster, make sure no play
  Would be great to get some opinions on how easy of a job this is for a bit of a noob. What to look out for/what parts will be hard/whether I've missed anything.

Thanks in advance!

These are the sources I've used to get the above info:

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have done the research and You have a good idea of what you want to do and how you are going to execute it. You have a torque wrench and know what the torque specs are.

The only thing I have found difficult about crank replacement is the axle can be tight in the bearing inner races and requires some force to get it through.

If you want to learn go for it. If things go wrong you can always go to your LBS.